# Disjoint unions in Isabelle/HOL

Tags: isabelle, isabelle-hol

In mathematics there is a notion of a "disjoint union" in which you "consider" all of the sets to be disjoint even if they are not. For instance, you might want to take the disjoint union of multiple copies of the sphere. It's the second meaning discussed in [this math.stackexchange question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1631405/455).

One more rigorous version of this notion, for an indexed set $\{U_i\}_{i \in I}$ is to take $\{(x, i) \mid x \in U_i \text{ and } i \in I\}$, but I am sure there are alternatives that work equally well.

Is a version of this notion defined (and proved to obey relevant properties) in any standard Isabelle/HOL libraries?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26926632/defining-disjoint-union-of-different-types-in-isabelle-and-more) answer your question? Disclaimer: I don't know Isabelle at all

Comment: @Trebor: Excellent find, but no. That construction allows you to take *finite* disjoint unions of *types*; I'm looking for a construction for *arbitrary* disjoint unions of *sets*. And since Isabelle does not support dependent types, I can't use the one to obtain the other.

Comment: Do you want disjoint unions of *types* or *sets*?  In ordinary ZFC set theory based math, there isn’t really a notion of type.  Spaces like the sphere are just sets, and maybe more relevant in ZFC they are all subsets of the class of all sets.  In dependent type theory it is easy to pass back and forth between the concepts and there is a natural notion of both arbitrary union of sets and arbitrary sum type.  I think it is a bit trickier in HOL.  But if unions of sets are what you want, you might look here: https://isabelle.in.tum.de/library/HOL/HOL-Library/Disjoint_Sets.html.

Comment: Actually I think `Sigma` in here is what you want: https://isabelle.in.tum.de/library/HOL/HOL/Product_Type.html

Comment: @JasonRute: `Sigma` is exactly what I want. Thanks!